# How to convert formulas to CNF, (P ∧ (P → Q)) → (P ∧ Q)

Tags: logic

is this the correct way to convert the formula into CNF,

(P ∧ (P → Q)) → (P ∧ Q) (Premise)

```
  ¬[P  ∧ (P → Q)] V (P ∧ Q) (Eliminate →)
  ¬[P  ∧ (¬P V Q)] V (P ∧ Q) (Eliminate →)
  [¬P  V ¬ (¬P V Q)] V (P ∧ Q) (De morgans law)
  [¬P  V (¬¬P ∧ ¬Q)] V (P ∧ Q) (De morgans law)
  [¬P  V (P ∧ ¬Q)] V (P ∧ Q) (Eliminate sequence of negation)
  ¬P ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∧ Q) (DNF)
 ¬[¬P ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (P ∧ Q)] (Negate DNF)
¬¬P ∧ ¬(P ∧ ¬Q) ∧ ¬(P ∧ Q) (De morgans law)
¬¬P ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬¬Q) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q) (De morgans law)
P ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬¬Q) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q) (Eliminate sequence of negation)
P ∧ (¬P ∨ Q) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q) (Eliminate sequence of negation)
P ∧ (¬P ∨ Q ) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q)  (CNF)
```

Comment: Maybe, after the elimination of all $\to$: $¬[¬(P∧(¬P∨Q))∨(P∧Q)] \equiv (P∧(¬P∨Q))∧¬(P∧Q)) \equiv (P∧(¬P∨Q))∧(¬P∨¬Q)$

Comment: $(P\land (P\to Q))\to (P\land Q)$ is always true, so its negation should be always false (whether in CNF or not).

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy That duplicate post is now gone unfortunately, deleted by that post author Sean Pilan. (Not to be confused with Sean Palin)

Comment: @Sean Palin please do not edit your OP to reflect a different question. If you do, then either (1) retain the old question, make it known you are editing, and add a new question, or (2) simply create a new post with a different question. Changing the OP to reflect a different question suddenly makes all existing repsonses appear irrelevant when in fact they were not to begin with.

Comment: @Sean Palin Also, you have changed the problem in your OP entirely. Originally you asked for the CNF of the **negation** of $[P \wedge (P \to Q)] \to (P \wedge Q)$. *Now* you are suddenly asking for the CNF of just $[P \wedge (P \to Q)] \to (P \wedge Q)$. Which is it? The method you have now provided in your post (that is, the method I offered in response to your original question) is a method for obtaining the CNF of the **negation** of $[P \wedge (P \to Q)] \to (P \wedge Q)$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach to obtain **the conjunctive normal form (CNF) of the negation of a formula $\phi$**: first, obtain the disjunctive normal form (DNF) of $\phi$. Second, negate this resulting formula. Third, apply DeMorgan's Law until you're left with a conjunction of clauses in which every clause is a disjunction of one or more literals. In other words, if $\rho_1 \vee \rho_2 \vee ... \vee \rho_n$ is the DNF of $\phi$ where $\rho_1, \rho_2, ..., \rho_n$ are clauses, then negate and manipulate the DNF of $\phi$ as follows

$
\begin{array}{ll}
& \neg \phi \\
\Leftrightarrow & \neg (\rho_1 \vee \rho_2 \vee ... \vee \rho_n) & \text{by definition of $\phi$} \\
\Leftrightarrow & \neg \rho_1 \wedge \neg \rho_2 \wedge ... \wedge \neg \rho_n & \text{by DeMoran's Law} \\
\end{array}
$

and continue applying DeMorgan's Law to every negated clause $\neg \rho_i$ until it is a disjunction of literals. Of course, the result will be a formula in CNF that is logically equivalent to the negation of the original formula $\phi$.

I apply this approach below, using only three of the inference rules you provided: eliminate $\to$, Demorgan's law, and double negation elimination.

First, obtain the DNF of the *original formula* $[P ∧ (P → Q)] \to (P \wedge Q)$ as follows

$
\begin{array}{llll}
[P ∧ (P → Q)] \to (P \wedge Q) \\
\neg [P ∧ (P → Q)] \vee (P \wedge Q) & \text{Eliminate $\to$} \\
\neg [P ∧ (\neg P \vee Q)] \vee (P \wedge Q) & \text{Eliminate $\to$} \\
[\neg P \vee \neg (\neg P \vee Q)] \vee (P \wedge Q) & \text{DeMorgan's Law} \\
[\neg P \vee (\neg\neg P \wedge \neg Q)] \vee (P \wedge Q) & \text{DeMorgan's Law} \\
[\neg P \vee (P \wedge \neg Q)] \vee (P \wedge Q) & \text{Double Negation Elimination} \\
\neg P \vee (P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (P \wedge Q) & \text{DNF of $[P ∧ (P → Q)] \to (P \wedge Q)$} \\
\end{array} 
$

Next, negate DNF and apply DeMorgan's Law. This will return the CNF of the *negation of the original formula* $\neg \Big[ [P ∧ (P → Q)] \to (P \wedge Q) \Big]$ as follows

$
\begin{array}{llll}
\neg \Big[ \neg P \vee (P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (P \wedge Q) \Big] & \text{negation of DNF} \\
\neg\neg P \wedge \neg(P \wedge \neg Q) \wedge \neg(P \wedge Q) & \text{DeMorgan's Laws} \\
\neg\neg P \wedge (\neg P \vee \neg\neg Q) \wedge (\neg P \vee \neg Q) & \text{DeMorgan's Laws} \\
P \wedge (\neg P \vee \neg\neg Q) \wedge (\neg P \vee \neg Q) & \text{Double Negation Law} \\
P \wedge (\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg P \vee \neg Q) & \text{Double Negation Law} \\
P \wedge (\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg P \vee \neg Q) & \text{CNF of $\neg \Big[ [P ∧ (P → Q)] \to (P \wedge Q) \Big]$} \\
\end{array} 
$

The reason I suggest deriving DNF first is I often find it easier to derive DNF than CNF, and once you have DNF, it is easy to convert from DNF to CNF via DeMorgan's law. Note the method I outlined above avoided any tedious applicaitons of the distributive law.

On the other hand, if you want **the CNF of a formula $\phi$ (not the negation of $\phi$)**, you can use a similar technique. First, negate $\phi$ to obtain $\neg \phi$. Second, find the DNF of $\neg \phi$. Third, negate the DNF of $\neg \phi$. Fourth, apply DeMorgan's law. The resulting formula will be the CNF of $\phi$.